# Conflicting DLL from two different libraries in C#

Tags: c#, dll, tbb

I have a C# project and it uses two different libraries.

Each library is organized into a different folder where all it's dependencies are contained in their respective folder.

The problem is tbb.dll is used by both libraries and of course they both use a different version of tbb.dll.

I don't load tbb.dll directly myself as this is a dependency of the dlls from both libraries. What are my options?

Comment: Reference the method by full name including namespace(s).  The using statements at top of module are the namespaces of the different libraries.  Often in the Net library similar situation occur where you get a warning message indicating to add namespace when two different libraries have same method.

Comment: Is `tbb.dll` (and the libraries that depend on it) managed or unmanaged?

Comment: It is unmanaged I believe

Comment: As far as I know, TBB has a backward compatibility so you can try to use highest version of library in both places.
BTW If it was a native application -- it should not be a problem (on Windows)

Comment: The problem with letting two copies of TBB run simultaneously is the possibility of oversubscription; each library will have its own thread pool, each limited to the number of cores (if you don't specify differently).  So the max number of threads running could be as high as 2N.

Comment: Unfortunately one library has linked the openMP library statically. Is there really bad things that will happen if two openMPs are initialized?